# How to load JSON objects with nested lists and dictionaries?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am having JSON objects which take the following form:

```py
{
    "docId" : "1",
    "links" : {
        "a link": ["endpoint 1", "endpoint 2"],
        "another link": ["endpoint 3"] 
    },
    "authors" : ["Thomas", "Peter"],
    "text": "This is the document text!"    
}
```

In order to load it with `SparkSession.read.json` I am writing all those JSON objects into one file `concatenated.txt` where each line represents one entire document:

```py
{"docId": "1", ...}
{"docId": "2", ...}
{"docId": "3", ...}
```

The problem is if I run

```
df_data = spark.read.json('concatenated.txt')
```

it does not work because I am running into a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. I don't understand the exact problem but I guess it's just not able to infer the correct types. For that reason I defined the following schema as a work around. This is working so far:

```py
schema = StructType([
        StructField("docId", StringType(), True),
        StructField("links", StringType(), True),
        StructField("authors", StringType(), True),
        StructField("text", StringType(), True)                              
])

df_data = spark.read.json('concatenated.txt', schema=schema)
```

but of course, this requires me to do someting like:

```py
import json 
# ..
df_data.flatMap(lambda x: json.loads(x.authors))
```

in order to have the actual underlying object.

My question would be how I can load the JSON data such that all the complex objects are actually constructed on load. So `authors` should e.g. always contain a `list` (or `None`), whereas `links` is a `dict` which values are also of the type `list`.

---

Sample data:

```py
{ "docId" : "1", "links" : { "a link": ["endpoint 1", "endpoint 2"], "another link": ["endpoint 3"] }, "authors" : ["Thomas", "Peter"], "text": "This is the document text!" }
{ "docId" : "2", "links" : { "a link": ["endpoint 1", "endpoint 2"], "another link": ["endpoint 3"] }, "authors" : ["Thomas", "Peter"], "text": "This is the document text!" }
{ "docId" : "3", "links" : { "a link": ["endpoint 1", "endpoint 2"], "another link": ["endpoint 3"] }, "authors" : ["Thomas", "Peter"], "text": "This is the document text!" }
{ "docId" : "4", "links" : { "a link": ["endpoint 1", "endpoint 2"], "another link": ["endpoint 3"] }, "authors" : ["Thomas", "Peter"], "text": "This is the document text!" }
{ "docId" : "5", "links" : { "a link": ["endpoint 1", "endpoint 2"], "another link": ["endpoint 3"] }, "authors" : ["Thomas", "Peter"], "text": "This is the document text!" }
{ "docId" : "6", "links" : { "a link": ["endpoint 1", "endpoint 2"], "another link": ["endpoint 3"] }, "authors" : ["Thomas", "Peter"], "text": "This is the document text!" }
```

Comment: Your error states that you don't have enough memory for your app. Have you tried to give more memory for Java VMs? How much data you actually have? How do you launch your Spark app?

Comment: Could you post 2 lines of your data? Is each row separated by newline?

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans Yes I have tried that - memory should really not be a problem - the dataset is comparatively small - I am very certain this issue origins from some kind of JSON parsing "mistake" or something like that.

Comment: @Bala I've prepared copy & paste sample data with 6 exact copies of the small sample I showed above (except the  `docId` differs).

Comment: Spark need to read your data twice - first to create a schema and then to actually read the data. So it could be that you just don't have enough memory to create schema. I doubt that there could be an error in JSON parsing. You could try to reduce number of records - e.g. take only few lines. If that works - then you need to verify if there is enough memory. You can use Spark UI for that. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498215/spark-sql-read-json-reads-json-input-twice) is how it works

Comment: Just loaded your data (in my laptop) and it works fine.  Check your `spark.driver.memory` at file `spark-defaults.conf`

Comment: @Bala Did you let it infer the schema automatically?

Comment: I will post the output now

Answer (score 0):

The file loads fine (Spark 1.6, cloudera VM 5.12).  Here it is.  Check your `spark.driver.memory`.

```
>>> sqlContext.sql("select * from json.`file:///home/cloudera/data4.json`").show()
+---------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|        authors|docId|               links|                text|
+---------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|[Thomas, Peter]|    1|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    2|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    3|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    4|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    5|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    6|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
+---------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+

>>> sqlContext.read.json("file:///home/cloudera/data4.json").show()
+---------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|        authors|docId|               links|                text|
+---------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|[Thomas, Peter]|    1|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    2|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    3|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    4|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    5|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
|[Thomas, Peter]|    6|[WrappedArray(end...|This is the docum...|
+---------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```